# How to convert List<dynamic> to 3D list?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So, I actually have a list from an API source? and Dart is taking that as List and I want to convert that to List<List<List?

Can anybody help with that?

I have tried this. But this isnt helping. Please help

````
         (row) => row.map<List<int>>((ele)=> ele.from(ele)).toList()
      ).toList(); ```
````

Comment: can you post input and expected output please ?